# Carrierwave/Fog-azure: azure is not a recognized provider (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, carrierwave, fog

I'm trying to connect my rails 4 project to Azure, I use carrierwave and fog for managing and storing the images.

This is the error I get when starting the server or the console:

```
/Users/giulio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@my_project/gems/fog-core-1.32.0/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:12:in `new': azure is not a recognized provider (ArgumentError)
        from /Users/giulio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@my_project/gems/fog-core-1.32.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:22:in `new'
        from /Users/giulio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@my_project/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:83:in `eager_load_fog'
        from /Users/giulio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@my_project/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:96:in `fog_credentials='
        from /Users/giulio/Documents/rails/my_project/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

I have in my gemfile:

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog'
gem 'fog-azure'
```

Carrierwave initializer is:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.test?
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false
  else
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_credentials = Rails.application.secrets.fog_credentials.symbolize_keys
    config.fog_directory = "my_directory"
    config.fog_public     = true
    config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'public, max-age=315576000'}
  end
end
```

my secrets.yml contains:

```
  fog_credentials:
    provider: 'azure'
    azure_sub_id: '12a2341c-22ac-1561-5ed2-17865d910ba4'
    azure_pem: '~/secret.pem'
    azure_api_url: 'usnorth.management.core.windows.net'
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking into `fog-azure` gem code I figured that fog-azure deals only with the 'Compute' module of fog, while `carrierwave` uses the 'storage' module.

From this I understand that the `fog-azure` can only be used for managing servers (i.e. starting, stopping, provisioning) not with the `storage`

I found also [carrierwave-azure](https://github.com/unosk/carrierwave-azure) gem to get carrierwave to support azure, I'll be trying this.